# java question: Is it a method?

Tags: java, class, oop, variables

I'm no Java guy, so I ask myself what this means:

```
public Button(Light light) {
        this.light = light;
}
```

Is Button a method? I ask myself, because it takes an input parameter light. But if it was a method, why would it begin with a capital letter and has no return data type?

Here comes the full example:

```
public class Button {
  private Light light;

  public Button(Light light) {
    this.light = light;
  }

  public void press() {
    light.turnOn();
  }
}
```

I know, this question is really trivial. However, I have nothing to do with Java and haven't found a description for the Button thing above. I'm just interested.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Button is a [constructor](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).

Answer (score 11):

That's a pretty valid question.

What your seeing it a method **constructor** which basically have the characteristics you have just mentioned:

- Do not have return type ( because it is constructing an instance of the class )
- They are named after the class name,  in this case the class is `Button`  ( The uppercase is nothing special, but a coding convention, java classes should start with uppercase hence the constructor start with uppercase too )

And additional note about your posted code.

If you don't define a constructor, the compiler will insert a no-arguments constructor for you:

So this is valid:

```
public class Button {
    // no constructor defined
    // the compiler will create one for you with no parameters
}

.... later 
Button button = new Button(); // <-- Using no arguments works.
```

But if you supply another constructor ( like in your case ) you can't use the no args constructor anymore.

```
public class Button(){
    public Button( Light l  ){ 
        this.light = l;// etc
    }
    // etc. etc. 
 }
 .... later 

 Button b = new Button(); // doesn't work, you have to use the constructor that uses a Light obj
```

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. Thank you all for the very detailed answers. This makes me love SO.

Answer (score 3):

Its a [constructor](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).

You must pass light as a parameter when you create an instance of the class.

Eg

```
Light l = new Light();
Button b = new Button(l);
b.press();
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a [constructor](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) for the Button object.

So when you write:

```
Button myButton = new Button(new Light());
```

That method is what gets called

Comment: The constructor is not a method.

Answer (score 2):

It's one of the possible constructor for the class Button.
Every statement that contains the name of the class and has no return value is a constructor.

You can define multiple constructor, for instance for differentiating the number and type of parameters such:

```
public Button();
public Button(int i);
public Button(int i, int j);
public Button(String s,int i, double d);
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Button is a constructor

Answer (score 0):

It is a custom constructor written in a Button class, Which accepts input parameter as a  custom variable Light. 
Therefore, in the `Button` class you will be having two constructors:

1. Default i.e., `Button bt = new Button();`
2. Parameter i.e., `Button bt = new Button( Light l)` which we need to pass

input argument during initialization.

Comment: The compiler won't generate a default constructor, so your sentence " Therefore, in the `Button` class you will be having two constructors" is wrong.